# Semantic Segmentation Multi-Class Single Channel Output Math

Tags: neural-networks, classification, image-processing, computer-vision, image-segmentation

For semantic segmentation problems, I understand that it's a pixel-wise classification problem. At the last layer of the neural network, I would basically have a 1x1x1 convolution layer with a softmax activation applied. The softmax activation essentially takes the depth-wise vector the output to generate probabilities summing to 1 (the highest probability represents the class at that pixel).

But what if I do multi-class segmentation in a single channel? Instead of the above, where I would have, say, foreground and background, what if I have classes 0,...n in a single channel? I would then label each pixel as either [0,....n], but how would the math work out in terms of the multi-class classification?

For instance, would I still be using softmax? I'm assuming not since softmax only sums to 1. I can't seem to find any references online, for some reason, for such a problem.

I realize that it's very popular to just have n channels for n classes, but it should also be possible to have a single channel with all the classes right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that if you talk about just having two classes (like a binary segmentator) then one class output would suffice. I've seen a nice discussion about this in the pytorch [forums here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/binary-segmentation-bcewithlogitsloss-pos-weight/71667). Then you'd use a Sigmoid layer and the BCELoss.

The main reason might be accuracy, it's more difficult to have the right threshold-ed values for n classes. Say you have probabilities (that add up to 1) if you have say two classes then it's alright (example. if value <=0.5 then class 1, otherwise class 2), this of course becomes more complicated as the number of classes increases (for 10 classes, if value <=0.1 then class 1, if value >0.1 and <=0.2 then class 2, etc.). Increasing the amount of channels in the output and then doing a softmax it's just more accurate (I've tried one class outputs with subpar results).

Even for binary segmentators haven two channel outputs significantly outperformed a one channel output. Indeed it's a valid question and more insight would be required.